rt.jar is missing in Java 17. What could be the alternate jar or where we can find JAXBContextImpl.class
rt.jar is missing in Java 17. What could be the alternate jar or where we can find JAXBContextImpl.class
Trying to find alternate rt.jar for java 17 version. Getting jaxb implementation is null.Please share alternate class of JAXBContextImpl.class or rt.jar of java 17.

You need jakarta.xml.bind-api  and jaxb-runtime as dependencies

rt.jar doesn't exist anymore since Java 9.

This is what I have to use JAXB:
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5</version>
            </dependency>

